# Azure Management API - TokenCredentials vs TokenCloudCredentials

Tags: c#, sql, api, azure, virtual-machine

Here's the latest version of the Compute prerelease that leverages the new resource group way of controlling access:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute/13.0.4-prerelease

Here's the latest version of the Sql prerelease that also leverages the new resource group way of controlling access:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql/0.46.0-prerelease

For the Compute dll all the constructors expect "ServiceClientCredentials" so you're suggested to use the TokenCredentials class with the subcriptionId and access token parameters.

For Sql dll all the constructors expect "SubscriptionCloudCredentials" so you're suggested to use the TokenCloudCredentials class with the subcriptionId and access token parameters.

It seems to me like TokenCredentials and TokenCloudCredentials are the same thing but tweaked inheritance. So what's the point of having two? Are they in the processing of changing from one one to the other and I just need to hold out for them to clean this up or am I stuck with having to manage two different Token entities in my code?